# I want function like sum() to add the all rows in a column of data type time in mysql

Tags: mysql

In my database there is table as below

```
+----+-----------+----------+
| id | fk_id     | duration |
+----+-----------+----------+
|  1 |        23 | 00:00:31 |
|  2 |        23 | 00:00:36 |
|  3 |       677 | 00:00:36 |
|  4 |       678 | 00:00:36 |
+----+-----------+----------+
```

In the above table the column duration is of data type time .

The following one is the schema of that table

```
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `durationof` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `fk_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `duration` time NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
```

Here the thing just I want to add all times in a duration column in a query, how can I?

Just like sum function is there any function to add all mysql time vales .

I tried select addtime(diration) from durationof;

But that is not working.

Comment: There is no such thing as "all rows in a column". A column does not "contain a row".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I completely disagree with [@Corbin's original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/13430672/3).  As documented under [The `TIME` Type](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/time.html):

> TIME values may range from `'-838:59:59'` to `'838:59:59'`. The hours part may be so large because the `TIME` type can be used not only to represent a time of day (which must be less than 24 hours), but also elapsed time or a time interval between two events (which may be much greater than 24 hours, or even negative).

To take the summation of all such intervals: [convert to seconds](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time-to-sec), [take the sum](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum) and then [convert back again](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_sec-to-time).

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(duration))) FROM durationof
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8cdf6/1/0).

Comment: Not sure I see a significant advantage of storing as a TIME, converting to seconds, and then converting back to TIME over just storing seconds to begin with.  I agree with your evaluation of the rest of my answer though.  In hindsight, it does need quite a bit of work...

Comment: @Corbin: The conversions are purely cosmetic/presentational.  Internally `TIME` is stored as an integer number of seconds anyway, so the conversions cost virtually nothing.  The advantage lies in using data types that correctly represent the type of data stored.

Comment: @eggyal: Thank you very much , i got exactly what i want .

Answer (score 2):

Instread of converting to seconds to do the sum, I would be tempted to just store the time in seconds.

In particular, Instead of storing a TIME, you could store some type of integer (int, smallint, bigint, etc).  You would identify your smallest unit of measure and store in that.

For example, if you care about precision down to seconds, store the durations in seconds.  For example, you might store `45` for 45 seconds.  If you cared about milliseconds, you would treat the data as milliseconds.  In other words, `45000` would be stored for 45 seconds.

Then you're back to summing normally.

---

Alternatively, if you want to stick with TIME, go with eggyval's answer.

Your specific circumstances will probably dictate whether TIME or an integer is better to work with.

Comment: Does MySQL not have an `interval` datatype?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Nope.  Not in the default installations anyway.  There may be some extension or engine that provides it.  I didn't actually know that some DBMS do have an interval type.  Out of curiosity, which one(s) do you know of?

Comment: Off the top of my head: Oracle, PostgreSQL, DB2, Teradata, HSQLDB. Probably others as well as this is an ANSI SQL datatype.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Interesting. Never knew that it's an ANSI specified type.  Thanks.  Edit: Now that I think about it, MySQL does have a psuedo-type for intervals.  For example, `SELECT DATE_SUB('2012-11-17', INTERVAL 1 DAY)`.  This is hardly a type though so much as a syntax.  As far as far as I know, there's not any actual type for intervals.

Comment: thank you very much , the rows in column duration are actually the difference between two timestamps, so those are the durations rather than time ,

Comment: @usernaveen No problem :).  You should probably take my post with a bit of a grain of salt by the way.  What has worked well for me in the past may not be the best solution for you.  There could definitely be a few advantages to the TIMEDIFF-esque route, but I believe they'd be outweighed by the many disadvantages.  If you go the TIMEDIFF route, you might not even need this table.  You could probably just calculate it as the sum of the differences each time and be fine until your data set became very, very large (and at that point, precalculating the differences wouldn't help much).